# JDBC Connection Successful Locally, Same Code Fails when Deployed

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have code connecting to an Oracle DB on a remote server.  When I run this in Eclipse on my local Windows computer, it connects successfully and I'm able to run queries.  When the same code is exported to an external jar, and put on a different remote Linux server, the initial connection fails.  I'm just looking for help on what it could be since it's the exact same code running.  Does Windows/Linux make a difference (I can't find anything platform specific here)? Is it something wrong with my JDBC code?  I've checked the credentials and they are entered the same each time.

```
public static String[] connectToDB(String dbUser, String dbPass) {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10:1610:mysid",dbUser, dbPass);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        writeLog("** DB CONNECTION FAILED!");
    }
```

Comment: Check in AWS if you need to add permissions (IAM roles) to the machine that tries to access the DB, update security groups and etc.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I'm not using AWS at all. I just wanted to mention that there is a similar question on StackOverflow but it is specific to AWS.  I removed that statement to avoid confusion.

Comment: What does the SQLException say?

Comment: Can you reach 10.10.10.10 from the remote linux server?

Comment: The address 10.10.10.10 is a local IP and it seems that you're trying to access such an address over the wire between two computers that don't belong to the same network.

Comment: Please provide the actual exception stacktrace (seriously, don't just log things like `"** DB CONNECTION FAILED!"`, make sure to log the exception as well)

Comment: Thanks alfasin, your comments led me to the issue which was the oracle jdbc jar wasn't being packaged with the external jar.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the jar I was exporting in Eclipse did not include the oracle jdbc support jar that I had added in the build path.